# Crash listView into onStart()

Tags: android

Hi guys i have a problem with my code. When i execute onCreate() is ok, onStart() crash.

```
@Override
public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.arrivi);    

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_Compagnia[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++) {

        RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_CodiceVolo[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    this.A_Compagnia = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_Compagnia");
    this.A_CodiceVolo = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_CodiceVolo");
    this.A_Citta = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_Citta");
    this.A_OraPrevista = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_OraPrevista");
    this.A_OraStimata = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_OraStimata");
    this.A_StatoVolo = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_StatoVolo");
    this.thread = intent.getIntExtra("thread", 0);  
}
```

if i comment this:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.arrivi);    

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_Compagnia[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

/*  rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++) {

        RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_CodiceVolo[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
*/      
    }
```

My application work... i can see arrivi layout and Toast with value of A_Compagnia[1]
The logcat in eclipse doesn't work after update...
You can see the error?
Thank you so much!

EDIT: UPADTE

```
@Override
public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_Compagnia[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

        RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_CodiceVolo[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    this.A_Compagnia = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_Compagnia");
    this.A_CodiceVolo = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_CodiceVolo");
    this.A_Citta = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_Citta");
    this.A_OraPrevista = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_OraPrevista");
    this.A_OraStimata = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_OraStimata");
    this.A_StatoVolo = intent.getStringArrayExtra("A_StatoVolo");
    this.thread = intent.getIntExtra("thread", 0);  

    setContentView(R.layout.arrivi);    

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
    05-17 14:28:10.742: W/dalvikvm(635): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gianni.g/com.gianni.g.Arrivi}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at com.gianni.g.Arrivi.onStart(Arrivi.java:37)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
05-17 14:28:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  ... 11 more
```

Java:37 is

```
            RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
```

SOLVED: I have forgotten passing this:                                  intent.putExtra("A_StatoVolo", A_StatoVolo);
:)

Comment: dont setcontent view in onstart, see the android lifecycle, Start from oncreate

Comment: you cant use `setContentView()` inside `onStart()`

Comment: i have moved setConteview in onCreate() but it always crash

Comment: then paste your updated code please.

Comment: I have update 1st post

Comment: **1st** of all **dont** use `onStart()` unless you understand the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). use `onCreate()` instead.

Comment: i have obtain the logcat.. edited 1st post

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` because following line

```
for (int i = 1; i <= thread; i++)
```

try change that to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thread; i++)
```

and test again, this is so hard to debug your code without seeing your logcat, but this is my guess

Comment: My application crash here... 
            RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+thread, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
            rowItems.add(item);
i have understand.... i use toast for identify crash

Comment: did you check my solution? what is the error on this line ?

Comment: yes...but doesn't work
i have obtain the logcat ..edited 1st post

Comment: indicate line 37 @ `Arrivi`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you initialize all String[] instance variable's? If you leave the " = new String[200]" you avoid out of bounds exception (because they have not an fixed length, and you don't check for length).

That said, you have to check for null values (this edit will only use the existed one's if you do not have the "new String[200]")

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i=0; i < A_Compagnia.length; i++) {

    RowItem item = new RowItem(A_Compagnia[i], A_CodiceVolo[i], A_Citta[i], A_OraPrevista[i], A_OraStimata[i], A_StatoVolo[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A_CodiceVolo[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```